# PUT Request in C# WebForms to update one parameter

Tags: c#, json, webforms, put, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on a web app that will manage WooCommerce orders, over WooCommerce REST API.

I'm trying to update the order status after the user clicks a button.

When I run the app, click the button, I get a 200 - OK status, but the order remains the same, no update is done.

This is the cURL example on the documentation:

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/727 \
-u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
"status": "completed"
}'
```

On Postman, i execute the query and it works just fine, adding this code on the body (raw-JSON), over a PUT request:

```
{
    "status": "cancelled"
}
```

Now, this is my C# code, on the onClick action of the button:

```
 #region Request

            string nuevoEstado = "trash";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlRequestInicial);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(apiUsr + ":" + apiPwd));
            httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            httpWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var serializaer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var elJeison = serializaer.Serialize(new
                {
                    status = nuevoEstado
                });

                streamWriter.Write(elJeison);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string returnString = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            ltErr.Text = returnString;
#endregion
```

returnString shows "OK", but no update is done.

Any help is muchly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it with another approach. I post it here in case anyone gets to the same issue I had:

I changed the method to a async void

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

protected async void btnCompletarPedidoApiAxnAsync (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

And I set a using block, changing the approach over a HttpClient();

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), laUrl))
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiUsr + ":" + apiPwd));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                    request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"status\": \"completed\"\n}");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
```